# Android uploading fils to server causing OOM

Tags: php, android, mysql, file-upload

Just needing some assistance here. I am developing an Android app to help people back up their files to a shared webserver (shared right now, might migrate to hosting my own server soon).

I have managed to get this app working so far on my phone (Huawei P9 Lite, OS 6), and had problems on one tester where it had OOM errors. I thought that it might be the device, as no one else had issues. Another user is now getting the error. The major thing, is that it is sporadic and not consistent.

From my research and my limited knowledge (ex-delphi developer here, everything was done for us :) I need to make sure that I delete references that are no longer needed.
I lookde at this page and I don't think I am doing anything wrong in the code:https://android.jlelse.eu/9-ways-to-avoid-memory-leaks-in-android-b6d81648e35e
I have gone through the code and I cannot find where I could optimise.

I have added the below to my manifest:

```
 android:largeHeap="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

Can anyone guide me here.

Part 2 of my question is, currently I connect to the server and check if the file exists, if not I copy the uploaded file. I think that this may not be the most efficient way to do things. Would it be worthwhile to check separately if the file exists, store this in a variable and then only upload?

Other things that I have contemplated have been:

Store filenames in a MySQL DB on the server, do a a separate query, and if not existing, upload. I contemplated using Shared Prefs, but don't want the user to lose progress if they reinstall.

Any thoughts? Code Below:

```
public class UploadToServer extends Activity {

TextView messageText;
Button uploadButton;
Button testButton;
Button LoginButton;
Button NewHttpButton;
Button newLogButton;
Boolean haveperm = false;
int serverResponseCode = 0;
int itemcount = 0;
int totalfilescount = 0;
int uploadcount = 0;
boolean busy = false;


String upLoadServerUri = null;

/**********  File Path *************/
String uploadFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/My Folder"; //- evenutally will be a list that will be looped through
String uploadFileName = "hello.png";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bugsnag.start(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_to_server);

    uploadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
    

    messageText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageText);



            /************* Php script path ****************/
    upLoadServerUri = "pathtoserver and php file"; // php file checks if the file exists and copies if not
    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (!busy) {
                busy = true;

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(UploadToServer.this,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permission is not granted
                    ActivityCompat
                            .requestPermissions(
                                    UploadToServer.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                    100);
                } else {
                    haveperm = true;
                }

                if (haveperm) {
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    messageText.setText("uploading started - please be patient as this may take a while");
                                }
                            });

                            File f;
                            
                            f = new File(uploadFilePath);
                            try {
                                
                                if (f.exists() && f.isDirectory()) {
                                    File file[] = f.listFiles();
                                    totalfilescount = f.listFiles().length;
                                    if (file != null) {
                                        itemcount = 0;
                                        for (int i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
                                            uploadFileName = file[i].getName();
                                            uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "/" + uploadFileName);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                busy = false;
                            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                                throw new IllegalStateException("Not found:" + uploadFilePath, e);
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            messageText.setText("Completed");
                        }
                    });
            } else {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Still busy with this, please wait",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

public static void displayDirectoryContents(File dir) {
    try {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("directory:" + file.getCanonicalPath());

                displayDirectoryContents(file);
            } else {
                //System.out.println("     file:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
    String fileName = sourceFileUri;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
    busy = true;
    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        return 0;

    } else {
        try {

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");//30122020
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            //conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(fileInputStream.available())); //took this out as it was causing exceeded content-length limit
            // conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);//20012021

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            
            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                itemcount++;
                uploadcount++;


                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        messageText.setText("File " + String.valueOf(itemcount) + " of " + String.valueOf(totalfilescount) + " Files Uploaded successfully");

                    }
                });
            } else {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "Failed" + String.valueOf(serverResponseCode),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }//close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            //dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                    //   Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        //  dialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //  messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                    messageText.setText(e.getMessage());
                    //  Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                    //        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Exception", "Exception : "
                    + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    //  dialog.dismiss();

        return serverResponseCode;

    } // End else block

}
```

}

Php file:

```
<?php

$file_path = "uploads/";
 
$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(!file_exists($file_path)) {
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: `buffer = new byte[bufferSize];` That buffer is much too big and causes oom. Better: `buffer = new byte[8192];`

Comment: `bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);` Remove those lines.

Comment: @blackapps - thank you, I shall try that.

Comment: bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize); - this uses  buffersize, what value should I then use here?

Comment: bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer); will do.

Comment: `dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);` That becomes `dos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);`

Comment: It's still giving an error for that user: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 16 byte allocation with 12905184 free bytes and 12MB until OOM, target footprint 536870912, growth limit 536870912; failed due to fragmentation (largest possible contiguous allocation 0 bytes)
        at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:867) ? Any ideas?

Comment: You could at least have adapted your code here. Difficult talking now.